# calling python with bootstrap javascript on mouse over and execute it

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

While reading bootstrap documentation, I got quiet confused, but I have read you can call python with javascript and I would appreciate if you could help me with my case.

I am running flask and python for backend stuff, however I would need to call python when html id has **on mouse over**.

Here is some example html:

```
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="firstbutton">Button</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="secondbutton">Button</button>
</body>
```

I know it's very easy to call change of a body background color with javascript, but for my work I would need to see a code for calling python.(I know, I know... But I would really like to see the process). Can anyone be so nice and explain me step by step in brief how this works. Would really appreciate it.

so let's assume:

- `onmouseover` > `id="firstbutton"` > body goes to red (background-color)
- `onmouseover` > `id="secondbutton"` > body goes to black (background-color)

Comment: `$("#firstbutton").on("mouseover", function() { $(body).css("backgroundColor", "red"); });` is how you add an event listener to an id to change body background color with jQuery. no idea what you're talking about calling python code...browser cannot execute python, only server, so you'd be making an XHR call if you need the server to do something.

Comment: Think about it like things. HTML is used for the content, CSS is used for the styling, JavaScript is for dynamic front-end things like changing content without refreshing the page.

Comment: Yes guys I understand all that. However I have background operations and I really need to execute python.

Comment: @Testingman then you'll need to build an api, then on the mouseover event you'll make an XHR call to your api which calls the server side python code

Comment: @Testingman What does your backend code in Flask look like? What routes have you declared?

Comment: this is for testing purposes. i have one route @app.route('/') to index page. On this page there are two buttons. In __init__.py I imported another python script which random generates the rgb color, which i would like to use to implement for background color of a body. That's it:)

Comment: basically: button1 random generates random shade of red and button two random generates a shade of blue. I am just interested how to call python, I guess it would be much easier to return values back.

Comment: and as well i am looking to that with onmouseover function this is very important for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something kind of similar using the code from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/jquery/ as a starting point.

The basic idea is to have a "helper route" which contains all the python you want to execute, and then use jQuery to send the data you want to that helper route. It then takes the data returned from the python route (as JSON, in this case), and then performs whatever HTML manipulations you want based on the data returned.